# Custom Prompt component in react-router-dom. Preventing the page reloading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using Prompt from react-router-dom to create my Custom Component for preventing users to leave from the Popup form.

```
const SignUpForm = () => {

  const { fields, onChange, onSubmit } = useFormState();

  const isEmpty = Object.keys(fields).length === 0;

  usePreventReload(!isEmpty);

  const promptMessage = useMemo(() => JSON.stringify({ fields }), [fields]);

  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
      noValidate
      autoComplete="off"
    >
      <h2>Sign Up</h2>
      <Prompt when={!isEmpty} message={promptMessage} />
      <TextField
        label="First Name"
        name="firstName"
        onChange={onChange}
      />
        ...

      <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="secondary">
        Send
      </Button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

If you don’t type anything in the form, then the popup can be closed without problems. And when you fill some value in any field and then try to close the popup you will see a custom pop-up with a warning that you can lose data.
It works great except one case - a page reload. To do this, I'm using the listener "beforeunload" but we can use only the system dialog in this case. But is it also possible to use Custom Component in this case?

I created a simple demo for you to get a better understanding - https://sin9k.com/custom-prompt

Does anyone know a workaround for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture window event "beforeUnload" to do this natively like below

so in componentDidMount you add this event listener like

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.pageRefreshFunction);
```

Then in componentWillUnmount you can remove this event listener because you don't want to leave it there when user go to other pages like

```
 window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.pageRefreshFunction);
```

and then pageRefreshFunction should have your popup trigger

But as per resources below the custom pop are not allowed anymore and you can only use native browser specific popups

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/chrome-51-deprecations#remove_custom_messages_in_onbeforeunload_dialogs

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event

Comment: Thank you, as i thought. It's impossible to do custom component